# How to have a checkbox label to the left of the form and the checkbox on the right of the form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building a form in **bootstrap 4**, however, I am unable to shift the label to the left and the checkbox to the right.

Using `bootstrap 4.3.1` :

```css
#checkAll { float: right;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="form-group form-check-inline">
    <label for="checkAll" class="form-check-label generalFrontLabel">Check all :</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" class="pull-right generalCheckBox">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using a `pull-right` class on the HTML but it doesn't work as well, I managed to make it work by add `margin-left` for the checkbox but it does not align well on different computers.

An example of what I am trying to achieve without bootstrap
https://jsfiddle.net/wfkey98r/

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this.

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: checkbox</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three checkboxes. The last option is disabled:</p>
  <form>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label style="margin-right: 10px;">Option 1:</label><input type="checkbox" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label style="margin-right: 10px;">Option 2:</label><input type="checkbox" value="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```